# Kindly help to change input type text to radio from the PHP code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to add and change the input type from text to radio button to use in my wordpress theme user profile settings like Gender: Male Female, but can't do the trick in the code. don't know how to change it.

tried with some code from w3schools given below, but that doesn't work too.

> Tried radio type, but doesn't work

`<label><?php _e( 'gender', 'themer' ); ?></label>
        <input type="radio" name="user_new_field" <?php if (isset($new_field) && $new_field=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="user_new_field" <?php if (isset($new_field) && $new_field=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
    </div>`

> i have to change the code to radio type, gonna use them in wordpress functions.php

```
 add_action( 'themer_after_user_profile_registration_fields_action', 'wpt_show_user_profile_custom_inputs' );
function wpt_show_user_profile_custom_inputs( $uid ) {
    $user_new_field = get_user_meta( $uid, 'user_new_field', true );
    $new_field = empty( $_POST['user_new_field'] ) ? $user_new_field : stripslashes( $_POST['user_new_field'] ); ?>
    <div class="field">
        <label><?php _e( 'gender', 'themer' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $new_field; ?>" name="user_new_field" size="40" placeholder="<?php echo _x( 'My New Field Placeholder', 'Placeholder for: New field', 'themer' ); ?>" />
    </div>



<?php }

// Save the field value from user settings page
add_action( 'themer_user_profile_extra_fields_update', 'wpt_save_user_profile_custom_inputs' );
function wpt_save_user_profile_custom_inputs( $uid ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['save-info'] ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['user_new_field'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $uid, 'user_new_field', $_POST['user_new_field'] );
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: which theme you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by replacing your code with below code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Extra Field", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">

    <tr>
    <th><label ><?php _e("Gender"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" <?php if(esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'gender', $user->ID ) ) == 'male'){echo ' checked '; } ?>class="regular-text" />Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female" <?php if(esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'gender', $user->ID ) ) == 'female'){echo ' checked '; } ?> class="regular-text" />Female
            <br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your gender."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php }


add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender'] );
}
```